# How to draw edges on top of nodes in Vis?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using [vis.js](http://visjs.org/)'s network diagram to draw a flowchart. I have some arrows that I need to overlap on top of some nodes. However, the arrows get drawn underneath the nodes. Is it possible to bring the arrows to the front of the nodes or draw nodes before the arrows?

I can provide some code and screenshots if anyone asks.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Vis.js network graphs use canvas and the Vis.js library doesn't have the concept of a zIndex (or similar) exposed in the API. In addition I think the edges generally just run to the outer border of the node, not through it. I think it might be worth looking onto other libs that have a specific flowchart feature.

Comment: In vis.js edges connect "central points" of nodes and the nodes' shapes are usually displayed above those points. There's no concept of z-index indeed although one can deal with that for nodes. Discussion and workaround for nodes can be found at https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146 , but I'm not aware of workarounds for edges if there's any.

Comment: Yes, I saw that post for nodes. I'm pretty convinced at this point that there isn't any way to achieve this with edges.

Comment: @DanielHong `On top`? Show us a picture of what you mean.

Comment: @YakovL Can you please paste your response in the answers section so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @stdob By "on top" I mean an arrow running over a node.

Comment: @DanielHong sure, no problem. So you haven't found any workaround, right?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I ended up curving the edges to get around the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vis.js edges connect "central points" of nodes and the nodes' shapes are usually displayed above those points. There's no concept of z-index indeed although one can deal with that for nodes. Discussion and workaround for nodes can be found at https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3146 (basically one can change the order of nodes and re-render, the last node is shown on top, the first on bottom etc), but I'm not aware of workarounds for edges if there's any.